# Spring MVC + jQuery datatables + thymeleaf + AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, datatables, thymeleaf

Can anybody point out where have I done wrong in here? I keep getting the `DataTables warning: table id=usersTable - Ajax error.

Ajax request :

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#usersTable').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/list",
        "columns": [
            {"data": "username"},
            {"data": "firstName"},
            {"data": "lastName"},
            {"data": "status"},
            {"data": "role"}
        ]
    })
});
```

Controller :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<User> listOfUsers() {
    List<User> usersList;
    usersList = userService.getAllUsers();
    return usersList;
}
```

UI :

```
       <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="usersTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th th:text="#{user.table.heading.username}">User Name</th>
                            <th th:text="#{systemUser.table.heading.firstname}">First Name</th>
                            <th th:text="#{systemUser.table.heading.lastname}">Last Name</th>
                            <th th:text="#{systemUser.table.heading.status}">Status</th>
                            <th th:text="#{systemUser.table.heading.role}">Role</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: which datatables version are you using? I have a similar feature but my code looks different

Comment: check this link https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Answer (score 0):

I share my working code:

Javascript side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#orderingTable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "/apiOrdering/orderings",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: function (d) {
                    return JSON.stringify(d);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id'},
                {data: 'date'},
                {data: 'docNumber'},
                {data: 'code'},
                {data: 'account'},
                {data: 'currency'},
                {data: 'debit'},
                {data: 'credit'},
                {data: 'description'},
            ]
        });
    });
```

Spring Boot Controller side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/orderings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public DataTablesOutput<Ordering> OrderingsList(@Valid @RequestBody DataTablesInput input) {
        System.out.println(input);
        return orderingService.findAll(input);
    }
```

Thymeleaf Html UI side:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="orderingTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width: 100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Sene</th>
                                <th>Dok Nomer</th>
                                <th>Kod</th>
                                <th>Hasap</th>
                                <th>Walyuta</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Kredit</th>
                                <th>Maksady</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr th:if="${orderings.empty}">
                                <td colspan="10"> Maglumat tapylmady </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr th:each="item : ${orderings}" th:id="${item.id}">
                                <td><span th:text="${item.id}">ID</span></td>
                                <td><span th:text="${item.date}">Sene</span></td>
                                <td><span th:text="${item.docNumber}">Dok Nomer</span></td>
                                <td><span th:text="${item.code}">Kod</span></td>
                                <td><span th:text="${item.account}">Hasap nomery</span></td>
                                <td><span th:text="${item.currency}">Walyuta</span></td>
                                <td><span th:text="${item.debit}">Debit</span></td>
                                <td><span th:text="${item.credit}">Kredit</span></td>
                                <td><span th:text="${item.description}">Maksady</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```